# embedding mono with C# "out parameters"

Tags: c#, c, mono, mono-embedding

I'm trying to embed a C# class in a C application using libmono, but the documentation is a bit lacking.

I'm trying to call a method with the prototype `void MessageToSend(out MessageObject message);`

How do i represent the "out parameter"? is it a pointer-to-a-pointer to a MonoObject? Thanks.

PS. as far as libmono is concerned, are 'out' and 'ref' parameters the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, it's MonoObject**.

And `out` and `ref` is the same for pretty much everything except the C# compiler.